# Simplifying $\frac{d}{d\theta}\left[ \int_a^b e^{(p(\theta)K(x)+H(x)+q(\theta))}\right]dx = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics

I am trying to prove that

$$E[K(x)]=\frac{-q'(\theta)}{p'(\theta)}$$

by differentiating a regular exponential class $f(x;\theta)$ with respect to $\theta$, i.e.

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\left[ \int_a^b exp[{(p(\theta)K(x)}+H(x)+q(\theta)] \space dx\right] = 0$$

I see that the $H(x)$ portion is $0$ and the $q(\theta)$ portion is straight forward, but am having trouble with the $p(\theta)K(x)$ portion.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The integral seems to be missing a "dx".

Comment: Thank you for noticing

Comment: Now the $dx$ is in the wrong place. :)

Comment: and you haven't closed the parenthesis in $\exp(\dots$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I am assuming from the setup that $\exp(p(\theta) K(x) + H(x) + q(\theta))$ is the probability distribution function $f(x; \theta)$ such that $\displaystyle \int_a^b \exp(p(\theta) K(x) + H(x) + q(\theta)) \ d x  = 1$. Furthermore, the required expectation of $K(x)$ is with respect to this distribution.

So, under this setup we consider the equation $\displaystyle \frac{d}{d\theta} \left[\int_a^b \exp(p(\theta) K(x) + H(x) + q(\theta)) \ dx \right]  = 0$. Using the [Leibniz's Integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) we have, 
\begin{align}
\int_a^b \exp(p(\theta) K(x) + H(x) + q(\theta))(p'(\theta)K(x) + q'(\theta)) \ dx   = 0 \\
\implies p'(\theta) \int_a^b K(x) f(x; \theta) \ dx + q'(\theta) \int_a^b f(x;\theta) dx  = 0 \\
\implies p'(\theta) \ \mathbb{E}[K(x)] + q'(\theta) = 0
\end{align}
Rearranging the above gives the required result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much.  It seems like it is a technique that I have never learned before, but it definitely makes sense.